# Protected properties in CakePHP behaviors

Tags: php, cakephp, callback, behavior

In the [behaviors](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/behaviors.html) section of CakePHP documentation the following statement can be found:

> *Since behaviors are shared across all the model instances that use them, it’s a good practice to store the settings per alias/model name that is using the behavior.*

That means that settings should be managed this way:

```
$this->settings[$Model->alias] = array(
  'option1_key' => 'option1_default_value',
  'option2_key' => 'option2_default_value',
  ...
);
```

I have developed a behavior that uses a protected property `_files` to store information between callbacks. Does the above statement implies that I should also index `_files` by model name as `$settings`?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that implies that :)
unless you want all model instances access to the very same content, of course.